# Can't view .aspx page in my MVC 3 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 application and i created a .aspx page that I am trying to incorporate into my project. The .aspx page looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.cs"    Inherits="TabletWebApp.Views.Home.Admin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="machineName" HeaderText="machineName" 
                    SortExpression="machineName" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TabletWebAppConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [machineName] FROM [MachineNames] ORDER BY [ID]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="parameterName" HeaderText="parameterName" 
                SortExpression="parameterName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="machineID" HeaderText="machineID" 
                SortExpression="machineID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="minVal" HeaderText="minVal" 
                SortExpression="minVal" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="maxVal" HeaderText="maxVal" 
                SortExpression="maxVal" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TabletWebAppConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [parameterName], [machineID], [minVal], [maxVal] FROM [MachineParameters] ORDER BY [ID], [machineID], [parameterName]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the controller I am simply calling this:

```
public ActionResult Admin()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

but when i try and view the page I get the error "The view at '~/Views/Home/Admin.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl."!

[Picture of resulting error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bLaS.jpg)

I have been looking around google and found this [Using the ASP.NET MVC source code to debug your app](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/)

but my project got build errors once i removed the system.web.mvc reference. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using WebForms for this page, not MVC, so `View()` will not work. It's perfectly legal to have a WebForms page in your app, but you can't get to it the MVC way.

It seems you can't put a WebForms page in your `Views` directory, and even if you could, you shouldn't. You'll need to put it elsewhere in your web app - let's say `/HomePages`

Then you'll just have to do a straight-up redirect, like:

```
public ActionResult Admin() {
    return Redirect("~/HomePages/Admin.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Just moved it into a new folder and it worked like a charm, thanks!